# How can I split a Pig tuple into subtuples?

Tags: apache-pig

Here are the tuples that I am manipulating in a Pig script:

```
DUMP A
(4,20,53,31)
(21,3,40,16)
(15,51,12,3)
```

I would transform this relation (A) into another relation (B) such as:

```
DUMP B
(4,20)
(4,53)
(4,31)
(21,3)
(21,40)
(21,16)
(15,51)
(15,12)
(15,3)
```

That means keeping the first field in all tuples and get one tuple by each field. In the previous example, each tuple must give 3 new tuples. I have a solution to get:

```
DUMP B
(4,20)
(21,3)
(15,51)
(4,53)
(21,40)
(15,12)
(4,31)
(21,16)
(15,3)
```

Which is the good result but with the wrong order (I use the FOREACH operator each time). I could get the right order by adding a field to each tuple and then using the ORDER operator but I think there is a simpler way to do so.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
-- T is the name of the tuple, and v[1-4] are the values in the tuple
B = FOREACH A GENERATE T.v1, FLATTEN(TOBAG(T.v2, T.v3, T.v4)) ;
```

If the values do not have names, you could also do:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE T.$0, FLATTEN(TOBAG(T.$1, T.$2, T.$3)) ;
```

Output:

```
(4,20)
(4,53)
(4,31)
(21,3)
(21,40)
(21,16)
(15,51)
(15,12)
(15,3)
```